# Specify MTA from LAN

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have a mail server which has got `postfix` installed. In the same LAN, there are different machines which can send mail via the `mail` command from `mailutils` and `bsd-mailx`.

How do I configure those machines (Debians) to use as MTA the postfix from the mail server machine?

I can't find a config. file for mailutils/bsd-mailx in which to specify the IP for the MTA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I should install ssmtp.

Answer (score 0):

bsd-mailx uses other tools for mail delivery. The tool you have installed may vary, but it is [one of the tools providing `mail-transport-agent`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mail-transport-agent). Check which one is installed, for example if it is postfix, you can configure it with

```
dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Replace `postfix` with your corresponding package.

This should allow you to define the host that should be used to send the emails.